# Highcharts + Highmaps module not working

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to duplicate the Highmaps Demos › Map bubble except that I want to add other charts to the same page.  When I load the Highcharts script and the Highmaps module script, the chart doesn't render. The browser throws a generic error. See jsfiddle for the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/hkjbn6wg/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);

        // Correct UK to GB in data
        $.each(data, function () {
            if (this.code === 'UK') {
                this.code = 'GB';
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
            chart : {
                borderWidth : 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'World population 2013 by country'
            },

            subtitle : {
                text : 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name: 'Countries',
                mapData: mapData,
                color: '#E0E0E0',
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }, {
                type: 'mapbubble',
                mapData: mapData,
                name: 'Population 2013',
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                data: data,
                minSize: 4,
                maxSize: '12%',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is printed, because you miss highcharts-more.js file.

Add the reference to this file and example will work.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hkjbn6wg/2/

Comment: That worked perfectly. Can you point me to the documentation for that file? I'm not sure how I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: In the console (developer tools) you receive an error. ONly what you need is click inside this link to check what is wrong with highcharts.